# Fetch запрос + jquery params ? (делать запрос на сервер)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как сделать запрос чтобы отфильтровать данные через params: {}
Есть url по которому я вывожу информацию (id, city)
Как делать запрос с query params чтобы с не грузит сразу 100, а только те где города Kiev

```
<template>
<div>
    <h2>Products</h2>
    <div v-for="product in products" class="box">
        <p>{{product.id}}</p>
        <p>{{product.city}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
data() {
    return {
       products: []
           }
        },
    async mounted() {
        const res=await fetch('https://burburbus.com.ua/api/temp')
        const products=await res.json()
            this.products = products.data
        },
    methods: {
         filterProducts() {
            this.products=this.products.filter(i=>i.data.city = 'Kiev')
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

В таком виде, но вообще советую подключить аксиос https://github.com/axios/axios

```
data() {
    return {
       products: []
           }
        },
    async mounted() {
        const res=await fetch('https://burburbus.com.ua/api/temp?city=kiev')
        const products=await res.json()
            this.products = products.data
        },
    methods: {
         filterProducts() {
            this.products=this.products.filter(i=>i.data.city = 'Kiev')
    }
}
```

Comment: я хочу в параметрах передвать массив городо который будет в arrCitites

Comment: Вы перейдите по тому урлу что кинули - это же не рабочий пример

Comment: А откуда я знаю что это за урл и отдает ли он что то по этим параметрам?  Я вам скинул пример что такое вообще квери парамс

Comment: Так условия тастка другое ! )

Comment: Какое другое условие текста из этого "Как делать запрос с query params чтобы с не грузит сразу 100, а только те где города Kiev"?

Comment: хорошо, как сказать если параметров не будет  - будем загружать первых 10 обьектов ?

Comment: Это называется пагинация, погуглите, но это тоже квери парамс

Comment: как передавать другой URL если нечего не выбрать в input (тоесть по дефолу URl)  - если выбрали тогда наша функция